# Парсинг серий с thetvdb.com с помощью Simple Html Dom Parser

Tags: php, парсер, dom, simple-html-dom

Вот есть код:

```
<?php
echo "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$numseries = file_get_html('http://thetvdb.com/?tab=season&seriesid=153021&seasonid=280441&lid=7');
$odd = $numseries->find('td.odd a');

echo $odd[1];
?>
```

Как на странице с [сезоном](http://thetvdb.com/?tab=series&id=153021&lid=7) (1, 2, 3...) вытащить с помощью парсера все серии и ссылки на них? То есть у каждого сериала разное количество серий, а как вытащить ровное количество? Еще в этом примере присутствуют Specials, которые не нужно включать в общий список, так как все special есть в отдельном сезоне. Также интересно, как вытащить все ссылки на сезоны.

**Обновление**

Вот я переписал:

http://codepad.org/yJT1Duiz (simple_html_dom.php не подключен)

Только все равно выводятся названия. :(

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю Вам нужно было так. Функция получает список серий, а в конце смотрит есть ли ссылка на следующий сезон, если есть, то запускает еще раз себя, но уже с той ссылкой. И так делает пока не дойдет до последнего сезона.

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include('simple_html_dom.php');
function getserial($link)
{
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html = file_get_html($link);
    $header=$html->find('div.titlesection', 0)->find("h2", 0)->innertext;
    echo "<li>".substr($header, 0, strpos($header, "&nbsp;"))."</li>";
    echo "<ul>";
    $list=$html->find('td a');
    foreach($list as $key => $element) {
        if ($element->parent->class=="odd" or $element->parent->class=="even"){
            if ($list[$key-1]->href<>"http://api.thetvdb.com".$element->href){
                $element->href="http://api.thetvdb.com".$element->href;
                echo "<li>".$element."</li>";           
            }
        }   
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    $next=$html->find('div.subsection a', 1);
    if (isset($next) and ($next->innertext<>"Previous Season")){
        $html->clear();
        unset($html);
        getserial("http://api.thetvdb.com".$next->href);    
    }
    if (isset($html)){
        $html->clear();
        unset($html);       
    }

}


echo "<ul>";
getserial('http://api.thetvdb.com/?tab=season&seriesid=153021&seasonid=280441&lid=22');
echo "</ul>";

?>
```